# IMethodSymbol.ReturnType is null and parameters are null

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

So I have this function which is just a test function and doesn't really do much:

```
public static Task<string> Method(bool b, bool b2, bool b3, bool b4, int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    Console.WriteLine(b2);
    Console.WriteLine(b3);
    Console.WriteLine(b4);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    return Task.FromResult("");
}
```

So I have some code to find this function, using the roslyn code generator, but when I use the SemanticModel to get the IMethodSymbol, doing this gives me a lot of null properties like the Parameters property is uninitialized and the ReturnType property is null. This only happens when I use the Task type or any other awaitable type as a return type or any async code.

When the function is async the IsAsync property is true but all other properties are uninitialized. This isn't the case with async void.

Does anyone have a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can use the MethodDeclarationSyntax with the properties you need in conjunction with the SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo to get the values you need.